# How do you connect to a postgresql db from a file NOT the command line?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a file which I want a beginning section to tear down a db if exists, then create one and connect to it.

Thus far I have:

```
Drop DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name;
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
<don't know what goes here to connect to db_name>
```

I have googled a lot and keep finding how to do it from the psql command prompt but not how to connect like I am looking to do from a file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use is mysql not postgresql.

Comment: well, the pg-specific `\c db_name`, then?

Comment: The question was marked as a duplicate incorrectly. Its author has clearly stated that he is looking for a different solution than provided in the "duplicated" question.

@sourlain probably you could try `dblink` extension, though that would hardly be a clean solution I think.